# checking if an array is contained in another, in reverse order, at least twice

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

> I wrote a C++ function hasMirrorTwice that takes as parameters two arrays of integers, arr1 and arr2, and their lengths and checks if arr1 contains all elements of arr2 in reverse order at least twice. Below is the function. I was wondering if there was a way to simplify it?

```
bool hasMirrorTwice(int a1[], int a2[], int size1, int size2) {
  int num_reps = 0;
  bool contains = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < size1; ++i) {
    contains = false;
    if (a1[i] == a2[size2 - 1]) {
      contains = true;
      for (int k = size2 - 2; k >= 0; --k) {
        if (i + size2 - 1 - k >= size1 || a2[k] != a1[i + size2 - 1 - k]) {
          contains = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (contains) {
      ++num_reps;
      i += size2 - 2;
    }
    if (num_reps >= 2) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

In the main function below, the output should be true.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int a4[] = {1,2,3,2,3,2};
  int a5[] = {2,3,2};
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << hasMirrorTwice(a4, a5, 6, 3) 
            << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Try implementing [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) if you want better performace, or simply use `std::find` after doing a `std::reverse` if you want to write less code.

Comment: Your call to this function doesn't actually compile. Also, why aren't you using `std::vector` instead of arrays?

Comment: @cigien sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the standard library [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) algorithm and reverse iterators. For example:

```
bool hasMirrorTwice(const int *a1, const int *a2, int size1, int size2)
{
    using ritr = std::reverse_iterator<const int *>;

    // first match
    auto itr = std::search(a1, a1 + size1, ritr(a2 + size2), ritr(a2));
    if (itr == a1 + size1) {
        return false; // no match
    }

    // second match (start 1 position after previous match)
    itr = std::search(itr + 1, a1 + size1, ritr(a2 + size2), ritr(a2));
    return itr != a1 + size1;
}
```

C++17 added additional searching algorithms that can be used with `std::search`. It's a small modification to add the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_searcher) search algorithm to the previous example.

```
bool hasMirrorTwice(const int *a1, const int *a2, int size1, int size2)
{
    using ritr = std::reverse_iterator<const int *>;

    auto searcher = std::boyer_moore_searcher(ritr(a2 + size2), ritr(a2));

    // first match
    auto itr = std::search(a1, a1 + size1, searcher);
    if (itr == a1 + size1) {
        return false; // no match
    }

    // second match (start 1 position after previous match)
    itr = std::search(itr + 1, a1 + size1, searcher);
    return itr != a1 + size1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, if it's for integers or characters, you could view the arrays as strings and with algorithm Rabin-Karp check if the reverse target string is in the string being compared. the complexity running time, usually, would be less than $O(|T||P|)$ with |T| being the length of the first target string and |P| the length of the string being compared.